# cannot see my ios device connected to access sqlite database

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, ipad

I have my iPad connected to my Mac mini. I am doing iOS development and want to access the sqlite database on my iPad for my app. I did this in the past using sqlite-manager tool/plugin from firefox(basically its like management studio for sqlite databases). Now when I connect my device to my mac -mini (osx mavericks) i dont even see my iPad anywhere connected to my mac mini. But it is charging the battery (so it is connected). Lets say I want to copy photos from my ipad to my mac mini, how would i do that?

The database for my ipad app is located at 
/private/var/mobile/Applications/C577E881-463B-481E-84F4-5C3564D0FC89/Documents/MyAPP.db3

How do i access that DB on firefox tool? If you need more info,please ask. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know to get access to the SQLite database from a device is to save it locally to you Mac. In Xcode 6.3 you can do this via the Window->Devices screen. Choose your device, choose your app and hit the sprocket button underneath the "Installed Apps" table. Using the "Download Container..." option you can get the .xcappdata file to your computer. Right click on the file and "Show Package Contents". The SQLite database will be in the AppData/Library/Application Support/APPNAME folder.